Spring Ambiguity
I am confused as to why we would use the @Qualifier and @Primary annotations. If we have to specify which implementation we want to use, and that then becomes the bean which we instantiate, why have multiple implementations of the interface? I might just be misunderstanding
public interface Computer {
// ... some code here
}

@Component
@Primary
public Laptop implements Computer {
// ... some code here
}

@Component
public Desktop implements Computer {
// ... some code here
}

Some RestController
private final Computer pc;

@GetMapping("/")
public String someMethod() {
    return pc.name();
}

So I know it will return a Laptop object, that is what I told Spring the Primary implementation is. But what would the use of the other interfaces be? I think the better question would be, can I implement the others using DI/IoC, if it is possible how do you do it? I have been searching for more information in the documentation but could not find anything that answered the question.
I still just dont understand why we would have different implementations of the interface if we are never going to fetch them from the application context and use them. Why even bother?

Your question is unclear to me. (1) What do you mean with "what would the use of the other interfaces be"? You have only one interface Computer, so I don't understand what other interfaces you mean. (2) What do you mean with "can I implement the others using DI/IoC"? What do you mean with others and implement in this question?

Let me try to answer this with simple example.
Regarding the @Primary annotation use case:

Consider the scenario where you have a Bean definition in a lib, which is quite generic. Now in your module, you refer that lib and you got the default bean but you defined a specific implementation as well, so you would like to define your implementation as Primary.

Regarding the @Qualifier annotation use case:

As you rightly pointed out, having multiple beans of a type, say Vehicle but having specific implementation like Cars, Buses etc. You could easily segregate with Qualifier names.


Thank you for your reply, I know what the 2 annotations do. My question is more about why have the level of abstraction and multiple implementations if I have to tell the IoC container which one to use using the annotations. Then I could have just had a single class? That is what I am not understanding
